# Shell Script not reporting correctly

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am trying to create a script which monitors the files sizes and grep the Job ID. The problem is the script returns only first ID even if there are multiple processes running. Any idea why this is not working?

```
#!/bin/sh
filename='bigfiles'
find /opt/Logs -type f -size +10k > $filename
count='cat bigfiles | wc -l'

while read -r line
do

pid= more "$line" | grep ID | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'>> pid.txt

done < $filename
```

Also I need to scan multiple directories and the script should scan for the files if the size of the log file reaches 25% of file system utilization. Any suggestions on how I can incorporate this?

This works if I use for instead of while

```
 for line in $(cat bigfiles)                                                                                       
  do echo "$line"                                                                                                
  pid= grep JOBID "$line" | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' >> pid.txt                                  
  kill $(more $line | grep JOBID | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')                                    
  bhist -l $(more $line | grep JOBID | awk -F '=' '{print $2}') >> hist.txt;            
  done
```

Comment: You'll want to paste your code into http://www.shellcheck.net to get some help with the syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to say why your script behaves badly since we don't know what the files that you are dealing with looks like.  All we know is that you are interested in lines that contain the string `ID` and that you'd like to get whatever is after a `=` on those lines.

Your script contains two unused variables: `count` (a string containing a shell command) and `pid` (an empty variable). You also jump through quite a number of hoops to get to what's after `=`:

```
more "$line" | grep ID | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }'
```

The `more` command is a pager, meaning it's a utility for *viewing* files.  Instead of using that, you could let `grep` read the file directly:

```
grep ID "$line" | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }'
```

But this is just letting `grep` do something that `awk` can do by itself,

```
awk -F '=' '/ID/ { print $2 }' "$line"
```

But we can do better than that.  Instead of saving all the pathnames to the `$filename` file, we can let `find` do all the work for us:

```
find /opt/Logs -type f -size +10k \
    -exec awk -F '=' '/ID/ { print $2 }' {} + >pid.txt
```

This will find all regular files in or below `/opt/Logs` with size larger than 10 KB.  For each such file, what's after (the first) `=` on each line containing the string `ID` will be printed.  The result of that will be saved to `pid.txt`.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

Answer (score -1):

```
filename='bigfiles' find /opt/Logs -type f -size +10k > $filename

for line in $(cat bigfiles)

do 
echo "$line"

pid= grep JOBID "$line" | awk -F '=' '{print $2}' >> pid.txt

kill $(more $line | grep JOBID | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')

bhist -l $(grep JOBID "$line" | awk -F '=' '{print $2}') >> hist.txt;

done
```

Comment: `filename` would be unset in the shell on the first line and you ought to get an error there when trying to redirect to nothing.  Looping over the output of `cat` is ugly. You still have an empty `pid` variable defined for `grep`.  I can't really see what this answer is trying to say.

Comment: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)